# Apple Developer Pay Out Currency

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, app-store-connect, developer-program

When selling an app or in app purchases in the Apple App Store and having customers paying in USD, EUR, GBP etc, does Apple do the conversion and then pay you in your native currency i.e. for me £GBP as I am based in the UK or do they just pay out in $USD?

Can you select which currency you wish to be paid out in, or can you connect multiple bank accounts to be paid out in each currency?

Answer (score 4):

You get paid in the country where you legally sign your developer agreement - you get [one bank account for Apple to pay in your revenue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54376/itunes-connect-can-i-have-one-bank-account-for-every-currency-i-receive). It’s up to you to handle the accounting if you choose to move money to different accounts in different locations.

[Apple publishes tiered pricing charts online](https://itunespartner.apple.com/assets/downloads/261020Apps-Pricing.pdf) and announces upcoming changes as developer news, so you can watch for the periodic changes if you wish to schedule price changes.

- https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=ul8i5to3

You will want to track which regions withhold taxes and which don’t and Apple provides you the exchange rates in effect when your account clears.

Read up on this at the Managing Agreements, Tax, and Banking Information section of

- https://developer.apple.com/support/app-store-connect/